# In Spring Data JPA how do I perform a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` without resorting to writing the SQL and keeping non-blocking versions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

So in Spring Data JPA I can do the following

```
Optional<MyStuff> findByFooAndBar(Foo foo, Bar bar);

@Lock(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("from MyStuff m where m.foo = :foo and m.bar = :bar")
Optional<MyStuff> findByFooAndBarForUpdate(Foo foo, Bar bar);
```

I sort of want to avoid having to do the second one, and simply have something like

```
Optional<MyStuff> findByFooAndBarForUpdate(Foo foo, Bar bar);
```

Comment: ```@Lock(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) Optional<MyStuff> findByFooAndBar(Foo foo, Bar bar);``` Is it what you want?

Comment: no because that would make findByFooAndBar lock all the time, I want to have a locking and non locking version without having to rewrite

Comment: There are other settings can add to pessimistic lock like time-out, derived queries idea come from the criteria part contains the entity-specific condition expressions of the query. It's going to be tough to add all those settings, hints to derived method name. I think your 2nd query is simple enough to do it.

Answer (score -1):

pass in LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE in the method. look into this for more details

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).